# Insert webpage in PowerPoint

Tags: html, css, powerpoint

Maybe this is a pretty different question but I need a free powerpoint add-in which I can insert a webpage. I used LiveWeb but the bowser does not support CSS3 and HTML5 so I need one who can support it.

What do you recommend me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the liveweb rendering engine as detailed in the faq - http://skp.mvps.org/livewebfaq.htm?